# PDF of the product of two independent Gamma random variables

Tags: probability-distributions, gamma-distribution

I am trying to find out the density of the product $XY$ of two independent Gamma random variables $X \sim \mathrm{Gamma}(k_1, \theta_1)$ and $Y \sim \mathrm{Gamma}(k_2, \theta_2)$, where $k_i$'s are the shape parameters and $\theta_i$'s are the scale parameters.

I know the formula for the density of the product of two independent RV https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_distribution, but I couldn't evaluate the integral.

I know the resulting density will involve Meijer G-functions, and I found this paper: http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0118065, but the Gamma distribution density in this paper is given as $$f_i(x_i)=\frac{1}{\Gamma{\left(b_i\right)}} x_i^{b_i-1} e^{-x_i}$$ with unity scale parameter.

Is there a formula to find the density of the product of two independent Gamma random variables with arbitrary shape and scale parameters?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What is amma RV?

Comment: Just in case someone stumbles on this in the future and needs the product of a Gamma rv and a *power* of a second Gamma, i.e., $X^n Y$, that's where the Meijer G functions are involved and apparently can't be simplified the way they can for $XY$. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4273438/integral-of-a-power-and-exponential-of-a-sum-of-powers-generalizing-gradshteyn/4274138 for the result of the integral for specific $n$. I haven't yet filled in the details so if you need the density of $X^n Y$ there's some more work to do but that should get you close!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $X \sim \text{Gamma}(a,b)$ with pdf $f(x)$:

[image]

and $Y \sim \text{Gamma}(\alpha,\beta)$ be independent with pdf $g(y)$:

[image]

Then, the pdf of the product $Z = X Y$ can be obtained as $h(z)$:

[image]

where I am using the `TransformProduct` function from *mathStatica/Mathematica* to do the nitty-gritties, and `BesselK[n,z]` denotes the modified Bessel function of the second kind. This is much simpler than requiring MeijerG functions. I should note that I am one of the authors of the software function used.

**Quick Monte Carlo check**

- against theoretical solution derived above when  $a =2$, $b = 3$, $\alpha = 4$, and $\beta = 1.1$

[image]

Looks fine :)

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so much :)

Can you point to any documentation about how this function TransformProduct works?

Comment: I should ask this in a new question, but in case you see this comment—can mathStatica handle the generalization where $Z = X^n Y$? That is, instead of the product of two Gamma random variables, you raise one of them to an integer power $n$ and then multiply by the other? $X^n$ will be [Generalized-Gamma-distributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Gamma_distribution&oldid=1048969673#General). My efforts to simplify the result by hand/Wolfram Alpha are failing and I wonder how mathStatica would fare. (I don't even need the exact density; up to a normalizing constant is enough.)

Answer (score 4):

In order to provide an analytical derivation and confirm the result, it is possible to proceed as follows:
Let's start by defining independent gamma product $Z_{2}=XY$, $X=Z_{1}$ and $Y=\frac{Z_{2}}{Z_{1}}$. Then we can write joint density using jacobian,
\begin{equation} 
f(z_{1},z_{2})=f_{x}(z_{1})f_{y}(z_{2})|J|
\end{equation}
where jacobian $|J|$ is,
\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial x }{\partial z_{1}}&\frac{\partial x }{\partial z_{2}}\\\frac{\partial y }{\partial z_{1}}&\frac{\partial y }{\partial z_{2}}\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\\frac{-z_{2}}{z_{1}^{2}}&\frac{1}{z_{1}}\end{bmatrix}
Then this equals,
\begin{equation} 
f(z_{1},z_{2})=f_{x}(z_{1})f_{y}(z_{2})\frac{1}{z_{1}}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation} 
f(z_{1},z_{2})=\frac{\beta_{x}^{-\alpha_{x}}z_{1}^{\alpha_{x}-1}e^{\frac{-z_{1}}{\beta_{x}}}}{\Gamma(\beta_{x})}\frac{\beta_{y}^{-\alpha_{y}}(\frac{z_{2}}{z_{1}})^{\alpha_{y}-1}e^{\frac{-z_{2}/z_{1}}{\beta_{y}}}}{\Gamma(\beta_{y})}
\end{equation}
In order to get marginal density of $Z_{2}=XY$ the product, we integrate out the joint density we wrote over $Z_{1}$

\begin{equation} 
f(z_{2})=\beta_{x}^{-\alpha_{x}}\beta_{y}^{-\alpha_{y}}z_{2}^{\alpha_{y}-1}\int_{0}^{\infty}\left[\frac{z_{1}^{\alpha_{x}-\alpha_{y}-1}e^{\frac{-z_{1}}{\beta_{x}}}e^{\frac{-z_{2}/z_{1}}{\beta_{y}}}}{\Gamma(\beta_{x})\Gamma(\beta_{y})}dz_{1}\right]
\end{equation}
Using the fact that,
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{\alpha-1}\exp(-ax-bx^{-1})dx=2\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^{\alpha/2}K_{\alpha}\left(2\sqrt{ab} \right)
\end{equation}
We will have,
\begin{equation}
f\left(z_{2}=xy\right)=\frac{z_{2}^{\alpha_{y}-1}\beta_{x}^{-\alpha_{x}}\beta_{y}^{-\alpha_{y}}2\left(\frac{z_{2}\beta_{x}}{\beta_{y}}\right)^{\frac{\left(\alpha_{x}-\alpha_{y}\right)}{2}}K_{\alpha_{x}-\alpha_{y}}\left(2\sqrt{\frac{z_{2}}{\beta_{x}\beta_{y}}} \right)}{\Gamma(\alpha_{x})\Gamma(\alpha_{y})}
\end{equation}

Another Monte-Carlo check confirms @wolfies nice result above,

[image: GammaProductPlot]

Plus an integral on the pdf confirms the accuracy of it to be the correct density. After integrating in R we obtain,

> integrate(gamprod,lower = 0.,upper = Inf,ax = 2,bx = 3,ay = 4,by = 1.1)
> 1 with absolute error < 6.8e-05