# How to obtain the PDF of product of two iid gamma random variables

Tags: probability-distributions, density-function, gamma-distribution

Suppose I have two Gamma rvs $X1\sim G(m1,\Omega1)$ and $X2\sim G(m2,\Omega2)$ and both are i.i.d. Then how to derive the PDF of product of $X1\cdot X2$.
Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Comment: How are they i.i.d. with different parameters? Are $m_1 = m_2$ and $\Omega_1 = \Omega_2$? Do you just mean they are independent?

Comment: Yes $m1=m2$ and $\Omega1=\Omega2$

Comment: This is a special case of [PDF of the product of two independent Gamma random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2396324/pdf-of-the-product-of-two-independent-gamma-random-variables). I think you should be able to derive the result [using](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_distribution)
$$f_{X_1\cdot X_2}(y)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{X_1}(x)f_{X_2}(y/x)\cdot \frac{1}{|x|}~dx.$$