# Residues of dual-pole Γ functions

Tags: complex-analysis, gamma-function, residue-calculus

In working with a certain [Meijer G function](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4274138/81266), I encounter an integral that requires I compute the following residue:
$$\mathrm{Res}\left(f(s); s = a+n\right)$$
for
$$
f(s)= Γ(a-s) Γ(a - 1 - s) Γ(b - s) Γ(c - s) z^s,$$
for $a$, $b$, and $c$ rational; $z>0$; and $n \geq 0$ is a non-negative integer. The idea is that there's always exactly one dual-pole ($Γ(a-s) Γ(a - 1 - s)$ will both blow up/down as $s → a+n$ because they get an argument of 0 or a negative integer) and a few simple poles—in this example, two simple poles, $b$, and $c$, though in my applications there can be more. I can deal with the residue at the simple poles, my difficulty is with the residue at the double-poles, at $a+n$.

A lot of the discussion about residues online involves rational functions with polynomial denominators, which I obviously don't have. Wikipedia suggests a [limit formula for higher-order poles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis)#Limit_formula_for_higher-order_poles) according to which the above residue is
$$
\lim_{s \rightarrow a+n} \frac{\partial}{\partial s} (s-(a+n))^2 f(s)
$$
but this can't work because the derivative is
$$(s-(a+n)) \cdot f(s) \cdot  \Big( 2 + (a+n-s) \cdot \big(
\psi(a-s) + \psi(a-1-s) + \psi(b-s) + \psi(c-s) - \log(z)
\big)  \Big),$$
and because each of the $\psi$ terms (the [polygamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function)) that are a function of $a$ involve

1. $(s-(a+n))^2$ both of which go to zero in the limit as $s \rightarrow a+n$,
2. $\Gamma(a-s) \Gamma(a-1-s)$ in $f(s)$, both of which go to $\pm \infty$, and finally
3. $\psi(a-s)$ or $\psi(a-1-s)$ as a "tie-breaker" also goes to $\pm \infty$,

so the limit seeeeeems to not converge?

However. I *can* use Sympy to derive the residues for various $n=0,1,...$ and the residues it gives me seem correct (I can cross-check them by (1) evaluating the Meijer G function via hypergeometric functions and also (2) numerical integration of a probabilistic expectation that yields that Meijer G expression and (3) Monte Carlo). I provide Sympy's residue for a few $n$ below, where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant:

**n=0**
$$z^{a} \big(- \log{\left(z \right)} + \psi{\left(- a + b \right)} + \psi{\left(- a + c \right)} - 2 \gamma + 1\big) \Gamma\left(- a + b\right) \Gamma\left(- a + c\right)$$

**n=1**
$$\frac{1}{4}z^{a + 1} \big(- 2 \log{\left(z \right)} + 2 \psi{\left(- a + b - 1 \right)} + 2 \psi{\left(- a + c - 1 \right)} - 4 \gamma + 5\big) \Gamma\left(- a + b - 1\right) \Gamma\left(- a + c - 1\right)$$

**n=2**
$$\frac{1}{36} z^{a + 2} \big(- 3 \log{\left(z \right)} + 3 \psi{\left(- a + b - 2 \right)} + 3 \psi{\left(- a + c - 2 \right)} - 6 \gamma + 10\big) \Gamma\left(- a + b - 2\right) \Gamma\left(- a + c - 2\right)$$

**n=3**
$$\frac{1}{1728}z^{a + 3} \big(- 12 \log{\left(z \right)} + 12 \psi{\left(- a + b - 3 \right)} + 12 \psi{\left(- a + c - 3 \right)} - 24 \gamma + 47\big) \Gamma\left(- a + b - 3\right) \Gamma\left(- a + c - 3\right)$$

I can soooort of relate these Sympy residues to the limit formula above, but I totally can't seem to find the pattern in the denominators above, e.g., 1, 4, 36, 1728, …

Where am I going wrong?

---

(Python code follows)

```
import sympy as sp

s, z, a, b, c, d, e = sp.symbols('s z a b c d e')
f = sp.gamma(a - s) * sp.gamma(a - 1 - s) * sp.gamma(b - s) * sp.gamma(c - s) * z**s

for added in range(4):
  print(f'\n**n={added}**')
  res = sp.residue(f, s, a + added)

  printable = sp.simplify(res.subs({sp.exp(a * sp.log(z)): z**a}))
  sp.pprint(printable)

  # for Math Exchange:
  # print('$$' + sp.latex(printable).replace("\\operatorname{polygamma}", "\\psi") + '$$')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Mess with the orders of zeros/poles.* Let's redo the computations:
\begin{align*}
\operatorname*{Res}_{s=a+n}f(s)&=\lim_{s\to a+n}\big((s-a-n)^2f(s)\big)'=L_1\cdot L_2,
\\L_1&=\lim_{s\to a+n}(s-a-n)^2f(s),
\\L_2&=\lim_{s\to a+n}\left(\frac2{s-a-n}+\frac{f'(s)}{f(s)}\right).
\end{align*}
Now $L_1$ equals $\Gamma(b-a-n)\Gamma(c-a-n)z^{a+n}\cdot L_{11}\cdot L_{12}$, where \begin{align*}
L_{11}&=\lim_{s\to a+n}(s-a-n)\Gamma(a-s)=\lim_{t\to 0}t\,\Gamma(-n-t)=\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n!},
\\L_{12}&=\lim_{s\to a+n}(s-a-n)\Gamma(a-1-s)=\dots=\frac{(-1)^n}{(n+1)!}.
\end{align*}
Similarly, $L_2$ equals $\log z-\psi(b-a-n)-\psi(c-a-n)+L_{21}+L_{22}$, where
\begin{align*}
L_{21}&=\lim_{s\to a+n}\left(\frac1{s-a-n}-\psi(a-s)\right)=\dots=\gamma-H_n,
\\L_{22}&=\lim_{s\to a+n}\left(\frac1{s-a-n}-\psi(a-1-s)\right)=\gamma-H_{n+1}.
\end{align*}

Comment:  thank you! The harmonic numbers!! I am a bit miffed, Sympy can't do the $L_{21}$ limit but Wolfram Alpha let me confirm it. I am so grateful!

Comment: Posted a very ugly but working Python implementation of this at https://gist.github.com/fasiha/d116270d49d1dd57a252d9fde3e7c9e5 with a couple of quick unit tests to verify correctness versus mpmath's generic evaluation of the Meijer G function (via hypergeometric functions). I'm most grateful for your help!